How does information sharing on a blockchain work?
I'm familiar with the concepts for cryptography as in "message" is transformed by an encryption key and rendered unreadable and can then only be read if one has the decryption key.
Furthermore I understand the principles of blockchain where a collective of users "agree" on the state of the network, the holdings of different accounts and transfers on the network.
So to my question; how does it work technically if you would like to share information on a network? I can imagine a supply chain scenario with the following participants

a) a T-shirt manufacturer
b) a shipping agency
c) a T-shirt store

a) would would make 10,000 T-shirts and thus have 10,000 T-shirt coins in their wallet. c) would like to conduct business with a), thus they use a smart contract to swap their coins, which could be for example stable coins, for the 10,000 T-shirt coins that are held by a). For the swap to be completed two more smart contracts have to be validated:
The swap between the a) and b) where b) recieves the shippment, then b) has to swap with c). I imagine that the store will burn the T-shirt tokens when they sell T-shirts.
My question is, are there any examples where participants share more complex data such as 5G packet data?

Complex data sharing on blockchain generally works under the hood of Blockchain Oracle, as blockchains are purposely isolated from external systems and cannot inherently interact with data and systems existing outside their native blockchain environment.
You can read more about this in the article provided by Chainlink.
Nowadays, using various easy-to-integrate services like Chainlink Functions, Automation, VRF, CCIP and more, the blockchains are truly unlocking their full potential whether be in terms of accessing, transferring and verifying off-chain data, performing complex off-chain computations or even chain-to-chain communications and interactions.
As an example of sharing complex data on blockchains, you can explore this recently launched application known as Tunnl which is serving as an end-to-end onchain marketing platform designed to streamline the deal flow between brands and creators. They are using AI-based verification (via Chainlink Functions) to ensure the content submitted by creators matches the requirements specified in the original offer created by the contractor.
I haven’t seen any example related to 5G packet data sharing on Blockchain network personally. But, in this research paper, they’ve touched on the potential of blockchain for enabling key 5G technologies, including cloud computing, edge computing, software-defined networks, network function virtualization, network slicing, and D2D communications.

Thanks, I'll have some material to look into. I'll check back here during the week to see if there are any more answers. If not I'll mark this is the accepted answer.

Great. You're welcome, @OskarPaulsson. Feel free to let me know if you need any other supporting information from my end. I'll be happy to assist.
